# How to query a WMS in QGIS and pan/zoom to selected feature

Tags: qgis, wms, query

I'd like to find a way in QGIS (plugin, script) to query a WMS service (Italian cadastral Agency) with specific parameters (municipality, map sheet, parcel no.) and pan/zoom to the selected feature.

1. Queryable WMS URL https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php
2. Example output of a `GetFeatureInfo` query in HTML of a point in the `CP.CadastralParcel` layer

[image: WMS query]

Looking at the `InspireId localId` field, the parameters I'd like to input and process to build the query are:

- Municipality code: in the example is the string `G273`
- Cadastral map sheet number: in the example is the string `003400`
- Cadastral parcel number: in the example is the string `1298`

Starting from these 3 parameters given by the user, I think it should be composed a string similar to the one in the example `IT.AGE.PLA.G273_003400.1298` to be used to query the WMS layer and select the corresponding feature, then pan/zoom to it.

I've found on the web this AJAX request that I think it could be used to parse the service for this purpose https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/ajax/ajax.php?op=getGeomPart&prov=%7B0%7D&cod_com=%7B1%7D&foglio=%7B2%7D&num_part=%7B3%7D%2F&tkn=%7B4%7D

In this article it could be found some further specifications https://medium.com/tantotanto/le-mappa-castali-diventano-finalmente-utilizzabili-821db2f84533

Answer (score 0):

You can't pan/zoom to a selected feature in a WMS, because a WMS doesn't expose any features, only an image representation of features.

A GetFeatureInfo request may retrieve multiple attributes, but only for those features that intersect the pixel point (x,y/i,j) in the retrieved image.

There is no way to go to any specific feature as part of a standard WMS request.